# May anyone explain the call back of the useState function in handleClick to me?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) =>  prevCount + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick = {handleClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am new to React and just trying to grasp exactly how it works. Where does prevCount come from, is this callback needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of how it works:

- Initialize a variable:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

**count** is getter that allows you to access the current value & **setCount** is setter function that allows you to update the value.
While **useState(0)** represents the initial value of **count**.

- Manage handler:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) =>  prevCount + 1);
};
```

Here, **prevCount** is a variable that holds the current value of **count**.
*You can name it whatever you like.*
**Work:**  On button click, `setCount()` increase with 1 because the *prevCount* act as current value & *prevCount + 1* means add 1 in current value.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

If you pass a function as nextState, it will be treated as an updater function. It must be pure, should take the pending state as its only argument, and should return the next state. React will put your updater function in a queue and re-render your component. During the next render, React will calculate the next state by applying all of the queued updaters to the previous state

Example:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

function handleClick() {
  setCount(a => a + 1); // setCount(0 => 1)
  setCount(a => a + 1); // setCount(1 => 2)
  setCount(a => a + 1); // setCount(2 => 3)
}
```

[Link](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTD_j-wLLYF1iIOYFpEeNjp01zFG08npOL1sA&usqp=CAU)